# Cruisecontrol custom charts

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have solved my [initial problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839306/help-needed-configuring-cruisecontrol-net-statistics-merge) with statistics gathering, but now would like to present the data in some nice charts (much like the default ones already in CCNET). I have followed what I think is the correct way to do [this](http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2007/05/21/adding-custom-graphs-to-the-cruisecontrol.net-statistics-replacement.aspx), but still nothing shows up. Is there a working example that I can see working that anymore knows of?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I just had to actually following the instructions, so I don't need help on doing this anymore.

Comment: For those who need it, the javascript changes necessary are noted in this blog post:
http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2007/05/21/adding-custom-graphs-to-the-cruisecontrol.net-statistics-replacement.aspx